# Customize location of .so file generated by Cython

Tags: python, wrapper, cython

I have a Cython package with wrappers of a C library. This is the tree structure of the package

```
package/
       _api.pxd
       _wrap.pyx
       setup.py
       wrapper/
              __init__.py
              wrap.py
```

Doing

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

puts the `_wrap.so` file in the top-level `package/` directory which is normally required in most cases. However, my `wrap.py` needs the `_wrap.so` in the `package/wrapper/` directory. I was wondering if there's a way in which `setup.py` could create the `.so` file in the desired place by itself without manually copying and pasting it in the location.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The output folder for the produced `.so` files can be specified as the first argument of `setuptools.Extension` function.

Here is an example for Cython extensions,

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages, Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules=[
    Extension("package.wrapper.wrap",    # location of the resulting .so
             ["package/wrapper/wrap.pyx"],) ]


setup(name='package',
      packages=find_packages(),
      cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
      ext_modules = ext_modules,
     )
```

Comment: Well, that helped. Earlier I was trying "package/wrapper/wrap". God knows why wasn't it building.

Comment: what if i want to put it on particular path like `venv/lib/python/site-packages/package/` ?