# Cython build path

Tags: python, module, path, compilation, cython

When I use cython , I use this commandline to compile my pyx file:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

With the `--inplace` argument , my C file , builds folders and pyd compiled python module go where my pyx source file is.

There a way to compile all this files in a specific folder?  I searched on google and cython website without findung anything.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31043774/customize-location-of-so-file-generated-by-cython ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
python setup.py build_ext -b /../../../../dir/ -t .
```